What is causing "Missing character: There is no in font [<fontname>.otf]/ OT!" errors
This is a general font question, so I am not sure what community to post it in.  However, I always get great answers in this one, so here goes.
I recently started experimenting with font design.  I began with FontForge just to learn the ropes, bought FontLab 8 to have the so-called industry standard to work with, and then found myself doing most of the work in FontForge because it is far more intuitive to use.  Both crash about equally often and all the "extra" features offered by FontLab seem like bells and whistles.  I am really impressed with FontForge.
I have created several OpenType fonts with FontForge, all of which will take months or years to finish, but I need to test them in XeTeX often just to see how they look in a real-world setting.  I notice that if I take an existing font and edit it, everything is fine when I compile, but my new fonts give errors like
Missing character: There is no   in font [DoubleStruck-Math.otf]/
OT!

After looking on the web for answers, I discovered that if I delete the .notdef glyph (something that I apparently need FontLab for after all--unless someone knows how to do this in FontForge), this error goes away.  However, I have already read posts that suggest that removing this glyph is not a good idea.  On top of that, I have noticed that existing fonts--which do not cause this error when loaded--still have the .notdef glyph, so why is it not causing a problem with those fonts?
Note that I do not need to actually use any of the characters from the font to get this error.  The lines
\newfontfamily\doublestruck{DoubleStruck-Math.otf}[NFSSFamily=DoubleStruck]
\DeclareSymbolFont{ds}{TU}{DoubleStruck}{m}{n}

are all it takes.
So something else is going on here.  I guess my main question is: how do get this error to go away?  I am not sure whether this is ultimately a font problem or something I can fix from within XeTeX.  My secondary question is: why do the existing fonts not cause this error and my new ones do?
Addendum --------------------------------------------------------------
Here is a very short document:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\doublestruck{DoubleStruck-Math.otf}[NFSSFamily=DoubleStruck]
    \DeclareSymbolFont{ds}{TU}{DoubleStruck}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
I do nothing.   
\end{document}

I am not sure how to provide the entire .log file without posting it here, which seems a bit much.  The portion related to loading the font (starting from where fontspec.sty is loaded) appears to be:
(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fo
ntspec.sty
(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/
xparse\xparse.sty
(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\ex
pl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l
3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count195
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
))
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fo
ntspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count275
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen141
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen142
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen143

(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fonten
c.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\Michael Dean Pugh\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fo
ntspec.cfg)))
Missing character: There is no   in font [DoubleStruck-Math.otf]/OT!
Missing character: There is no   in font [DoubleStruck-Math.otf]/OT!
Missing character: There is no   in font [DoubleStruck-Math.otf]/OT:language=df
lt;!

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'DoubleStruck' created for font
(fontspec)             'DoubleStruck-Math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [NFSSFamily=DoubleStruck].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[DoubleStruck-Math.otf]/OT:language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

\symds=\mathgroup4

I am running this from TeXStudio.  There is more in the log file.  I can provide the entire file and the font (.otf) file if I can figure out how to include it.
Also, if I compile with LuaTeX, the analogous portion of the log file is:
("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/f
ontspec.sty"
("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages
/xparse/xparse.sty"
("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/e
xpl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/
l3backend-luatex.def"
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count197
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
))
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2024/02/13 2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/f
ontspec-luatex.sty"
Package: fontspec-luatex 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen141
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen142

("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/fonte
nc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:/Users/Michael Dean Pugh/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/f
ontspec.cfg")))
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script latn
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'DoubleStruck' created for font
(fontspec)             'DoubleStruck-Math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [NFSSFamily=DoubleStruck].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[DoubleStruck-Math.otf]:mode=node;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

\symds=\mathgroup4


@David Carlisle No, I copied that message exactly.  I agree there is probably a character there, but it must be unprintable because it shows up as a space.  And as I said, I haven't actually used any characters.  You are right also that if I attempt to use a character that is not in the font, I will get this error.  But here all I am doing is loading it and it still gives me the error.

@David Carlisle I am also not using unicode-math (yet).  Part of the reason I started exploring this avenue was to eventually get around to being able to use unicode-math (which presently I avoid because of MathTime Pro II).  But as of now, I am in the very basic stages.

@David Carlisle Okay.  Let me work on that.  It shouldn't take too long.

@David Carlisle I am not sure I included enough in the edit.  How do I get the .log and .otf files posted if you need them?

Using a similar small subset font with a current texlive xetex, the error message is slightly more informative as it gives the unicode slot as well as the actual character.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\doublestruck{Yinit.otf}[NFSSFamily=DoubleStruck]
    \DeclareSymbolFont{ds}{TU}{DoubleStruck}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
I do nothing.   
\end{document}

gives
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [Yinit.otf]/OT!
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [Yinit.otf]/OT!
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [Yinit.otf]/OT:language=dflt;
!

with xelatex and
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script latn
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script dflt

with lualatex.
The Yinit font is (despite this being a "unicode" OpenType version of the font) a subset font just consisting of upper case A-Z so some warnings are expected that things are missing. As the font isn't used as a normal text font this doesn't really matter. I suspect the same is true of your double struck font.
The simplest way to silence the xetex warning would be to add an explicit space character to the font as U+0020.

That did the trick!  I can only imagine how long it might have taken me to figure that out on my own.  Thank you, again!

@MikePugh note the message you show has three spaces it is saying no x in font ...   but here x is a space. the texlive version (but apparently not miktex)  added the U+.... bit a while ago specifically to make spotting unprintable characters easier
